# Location tracing using services in android

Tags: android, android-location

i want a background service class  that which will get the  user current location sends as a notification to the user if the user changes its location then the updated location will sends back to the user as a notification..even if the user close the application then also will receive the notification (the service will trace the location in background even application closed)

currently i am using [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/) service for tracing the location which works if the application in foreground

can u pls. help me to get out of this i am struggling for 4 hours

Comment: Use [Monitoring Geofences](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) method to solve your issue.Here you can track particular location user enter that location or leave that location.

Comment: how we can achieve this  using geofence can u explain it

Answer (score 1):

in your activity unlike the one that you are using make your buttons start and stop the service and it will run in the background unless the user reopens the app and stops it

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,gpsservice.class);

            startService(new Intent(i));
```

or to stop

```
Intent j = new Intent(MainActivity.this,gpsservice.class);

            stopService(new Intent(j));
```

use this service

```
public class gpsservice extends Service{

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    MyLocationListener locationListenerp;
    public gpsservice() {


    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        locationManager = (LocationManager) 
                getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationListenerp = new MyLocationListener();  
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(  
        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListenerp);




    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerp);



    }
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "location Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    }

     public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I was here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {            
            }
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }
}
```